# Reading from kinesis data streams in batch

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-kinesis

I'm reading from kinesis data streams after every 10 seconds and batching the data using nodejs and redis, the data volume in one batch is expected to touch upto 500 data (json payload),

I've used a checkpointing method where I keep the track of the sequence number of the last read record and then read from that number in next request.

I have used library like p-map for parallelism but not sure whether or not the script will be able to handle such volume or not.

Here is my code below :-

```
const {
  KinesisClient,
  GetShardIteratorCommand,
  GetRecordsCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-kinesis");
const { format } = require("date-fns");
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const pMap = require("p-map");
const sleep = require("sleep-promise");
const retry = require("async-retry");

// Configurable variables
const region = "<my-region>";
const streamName = "<my-stream>";
const shardId = "<my-shardId>";
const batchSize = 30; // Maximum number of records to process in each batch
const bufferMaxSize = 150; // Maximum number of records to buffer before writing to DB
const bufferMaxSizeBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // Maximum size of buffer (in bytes) before writing to DB

// Initialize Kinesis client
const kinesis = new KinesisClient({ region });

// Initialize Redis client
const redis = new Redis();

// Initialize variables
let shardIterator;
let buffer = [];
let bufferBytes = 0;
let lastSequenceNumber = null;

const processRecord = (record) => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(record.Data).toString("utf-8"));
  const timestamp = format(new Date(payload.time), "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", {
    timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata", // IST timezone
  });
  return {
    ...payload,
    time: timestamp,
  };
};

const processRecords = async (records) => {
  const items = records.map(processRecord);
  buffer.push(...items);
  bufferBytes += Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(items));
  if (buffer.length >= bufferMaxSize || bufferBytes >= bufferMaxSizeBytes) {
    await redis.publish("bufferFull", JSON.stringify(buffer));
    buffer = [];
    bufferBytes = 0;
  }
  lastSequenceNumber = records[records.length - 1].SequenceNumber;
  await redis.set("lastSequenceNumber", lastSequenceNumber);
};

const getShardIterator = async () => {
  lastSequenceNumber = await redis.get("lastSequenceNumber");
  const command = new GetShardIteratorCommand({
    StreamName: streamName,
    ShardId: shardId,
    ShardIteratorType: lastSequenceNumber
      ? "AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
      : "TRIM_HORIZON",
    StartingSequenceNumber: lastSequenceNumber,
  });
  const response = await kinesis.send(command);
  shardIterator = response.ShardIterator;
};

const readFromShard = async () => {
  const command = new GetRecordsCommand({
    ShardIterator: shardIterator,
    Limit: batchSize,
  });
  const response = await kinesis.send(command);
  if (response.Records.length > 0) {
    await processRecords(response.Records);
  }
  shardIterator = response.NextShardIterator;
};

const transformAndWriteToDB = async (items) => {
  await pMap(
    items,
    async (item) => {
      const { device_id, ...data } = item;
      await db.collection(`data_${device_id}`).insertOne(data);
    },
    { concurrency: 10 }
  );
};

redis.on("message", async (channel, message) => {
  if (channel === "bufferFull") {
    const items = JSON.parse(message);
    await transformAndWriteToDB(items);
  }
});

const run = async () => {
  await getShardIterator();
  while (true) {
    await retry(
      async () => {
        await readFromShard();
        await sleep(10000); // Sleep for 10 seconds
      },
      {
        retries: 5, // Number of retry attempts
        minTimeout: 1000,
        maxTimeout: 5000, // Maximum delay between retries (in milliseconds)
      }
    );
  }
};
run();
```

Also not sure whether p-map handles execution concurrently or parallelly, I want to handle the epoch conversion to timestamp parallely, also writing the database.

Will this code be able to handle the expected volume or there are some changes needed to the code to be production ready for the system.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks